# show "No Title" if a column in SQLite is empty

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I made a note app and I give users an option to leave the title of their note empty. But in RecyclerView and Toolbar title is shown and in this case it's empty. I tried to give value to that column while creating the table but it doesn't work.

Here's the code to create table:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TITLE + " TEXT DEFAULT 'No Title'," +
            CONTENT + " TEXT," +
            DATE + " TEXT," +
            TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Save method in adding note:

```
 private void saveNote() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title.getText()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(content.getText())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write Something in your note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        NotePad notePad = new NotePad(title.getText().toString(), content.getText().toString(), currentDate, currentTime);
        Database database = new Database(this);
        database.addNote(notePad);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        moveToList();
    }

}
```

add note method in database:

```
void addNote(NotePad notePad) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TITLE, notePad.getTitle());
    cv.put(CONTENT, notePad.getContent());
    cv.put(DATE, notePad.getDate());
    cv.put(TIME, notePad.getTime());

    database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: If you added the code: `...DEFAULT 'No Title'` to the create statement after you first ran the app then you must uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun so the db is recreated.

Comment: Actually I did it but I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Try it in a clean device.

Comment: I tried but same result...

Comment: Then the problem must be in the code that you use to display the note in the RecyclerView.

Comment: well when it has title it's okay. I opened database with sqlite viewer and still title column is empty

Comment: Post the code that saves the rows to the table.

Comment: @forpas I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `addNote()` you should **not** set a value in the `ContentValues` object for `TITLE` if it is empty, so SQLite will set the column's value to the default value:

```
void addNote(NotePad notePad) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cv = new ContentValues();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notePad.getTitle())) cv.put(TITLE, notePad.getTitle());
    cv.put(CONTENT, notePad.getContent());
    cv.put(DATE, notePad.getDate());
    cv.put(TIME, notePad.getTime());

    database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.You are a savior. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL while fetching data . For example

```
  Select IFNULL(“TITLE”,”NO TITLE”)  from table...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where exactly should I use it?

Comment: while getting data from DB.